# Email Routing Rules in Exchange

Tags: office365, exchange

We're trying to create a rule where any emails with attachments to a certain address are declined. It doesn't appear to be working at all though

We currently have it set like this [Routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tlzQ.png)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a rule in front of it that has stop processing on that is touching the email before this rule can execute? Otherwise, try moving this rule to the top of the list to test

Comment: Hey, This is the only routing rule we have so currently is at the top of the list I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

When testing on my side, it works:

[image]
[image]

Have you tried recreating this rule? We can also create another rule to see if issue occurs to all rules.

Use this command to confirm details:
Get-TransportRule "name" | Format-List

As mentioned in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b05e60b6-d8f2-419c-a010-d6b1f82568a2/office-365-transport-rules-stopped-working?forum=onlineservicesexchange), We can only check from front-end, such as whether are those rules created correctly. About why are those rules not working, you may need to submit Office 365 service request which could check from back end.